# How to install MaaS correctly in Ubuntu Server 14.04 Trusty and commit nodes

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, juju, maas

I have been trying to install MaaS on my laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 server. I installed maas with `Mutiple server install with MAAS` and its running fine.

Then I imported pxe-boot images and currently showing 12 images.

Next I installed Oracle Virtualbox to add nodes to MAAS. First I added a vm with 1024 ram 8GB and 1 processor with Bridged Adapter and added the same parameters in maas node with the MAC address and Wake-on-LAN power type and started the vm with network boot.

But the status is still at the commissioning state and the vm is loaded with pxelinux.0 image and terminates the vm boot prompting "could not start download". I tried number of methods and nothing seems to work on making nodes work for MAAS. I even tried again booting with a server image and setting the MAAS server ip as the parent ip. But still couldn't get the node up.

Can anyone suggest a method to successfully install nodes in maas for this particular case?

My procedure was

```
Install Ubuntu Server 14.04 Mutiple server install with MAAS in my laptop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo maas createsuperuser // with root
sudo maas-import-pxe-files
```

and used

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-region-controller
sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-cluster-controller
```

to setup network if its changed.

Comment: Is your network connected to the external world?

Comment: yep. Its connected to the external network through a proxy server. There is a separate DHCP server too.  This is a university network and I'm a student there :-)

Comment: Check to see what IP the node thinks the pxe server is.  I have not set up a MaaS system with out MaaS being the DHCP and DNS server.  You might try, first, to use it as an internal network to your machine, and have your machine be the proxy.  If you are raw on the school network, you don't have much control.  It will also let you debug one thing at a time.

Comment: If you have seperate DHCP server, you have to set that server to tell booting machines where the PXE image source is.  If you can't do that with the network (I doubt they will let you mess with their system), you will need to be providing your own DHCP, which means you are on your own subnet.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yep I think that was the case :) Our faculty DHCP Server doesn't allow to pxe boot the Oracle VM Nodes. Can you give some information where I can find the way to configure maas dhcp and dns to work locally?

Comment: You *have* to have a separate subnet, that is, a network where you answer the DHCP requests.  If you do that on your university network, I can tell you from experience that your IT department will end up very annoyed.

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate network on which you control the DHCP service.  That service tells clients where to go for PXE boot images.  If you are running virtualBox machines, all on your machine, you can set their nics as being on "internal network", and have your server be on that network as well. Then set up your MaaS server as DHCP.  you may have to turn DHCP off in virtualBox, not sure.  See Oracle VM VirtualBox help, section 6.6.

If you are using real hardware, you either need to get your IT to build you a network (probably won't do it), or you can buy a switch with a WAN port, and hang all your hardware off it.  The WAN port will protect the university network from your DHCP server, and your clients from their DHCP server.

You can either turn the DHCP off on you rswitch, and have MaaS handle DHCP, or you can configure the switch to point PXE requests to the MaaS server.  My experience was that it was simpler to turn DHCP off on the switch and just let MaaS handle everything.

[edit]

Once you set up the Virtual Box internal network, you need to, from the MaaS web gui, select the "Networks" tab and add a new network, specifying the IP addresses request.

Go to the "Settings" tab and scroll down to network settings and make sure they are correct.

Go to the "Cluster" tab and scroll down to "Interfaces".  That is where you set up the nic (it should be the virtualBox nic) you are using and whether or not the cluster handles DHCP, what the address and ranges are, etc.